# Error : Relation ‘fieldName’ is self referencing and multiple relation instances match

Tags: content-hub

We create a Relation field in the Content hub and needed to sync this field value in some products in Sitecore Commerce.

So to get this value in our backend code, we used the below –

```
IRelation relation = arg.Entity.GetRelation("fieldName");
```

But while executing the code we got an error –

> Relation ‘fieldName’ is self referencing and multiple relation
> instances match. Specify the relation role.
>
> at Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Models.Base.RelationContainer.GetRelation()
>
> at
> Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Models.Base.RelationContainer.GetRelation(Nullable`1
> role)
>
> at Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Models.Base.RelationManager.GetRelation(String
> name, Nullable`1 role)
>
> –                arg.Entity.GetRelation(“Relations”,
> RelationRole.Child)        {Relations.ChildToManyParentsRelation}
> Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Contracts.Base.IRelation
> {Stylelabs.M.Sdk.WebClient.Models.Relations.ChildToManyParentsRelation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this we need to pass the second parameter which is `RelationRole` like below –

```
IRelation relation = arg.Entity.GetRelation("fieldName", RelationRole.Parent);
```

This relation role can be 2 types -

1. RelationRole.Parent
2. RelationRole.Child

You can use either as per your requirements. Because if you create a Relation field it will create 2 fields automatically, one is child relation and the other is parent relation.

[image]

After doing the above change, we were able to find a relation successfully.

I also wrote a blog for this - https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2022/08/25/888/